# "a//abc".lstrip("a:/") becomes "bc". Why?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I've encountered this now and I can't understand what's going on here...:

```
"a//abc".lstrip("a:/")
# "bc"
```

Another example:

```
"a//bcd".lstrip("a:/")
# "bcd"
```

Does ":" perhaps have a special meaning for the stripping functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `lstrip` removes **all characters of a set**, not a **substring**

If you want to remove a substring from the start of a string only, I usually do:

```
# data = "a//abc"
# subs = "a:/"
if data.startswith(subs):
    data = data[len(subs):]
```